# Make specific randomly generated codes with timer

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make randomly generated codes when a timer is finished.

But I would like to use this code `ABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`

on this format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX (replace X with a randomly generated number/letter)

And I would like to insert the code in this

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(3)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "replace textbox by code"
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what problem are you having?

Comment: If you're a noob to VB as well as VB.NET, let me strongly suggest that you learn C# instead of VB.NET.  It's much more prevalent than VB.NET;  you'll find more sample code in C# and be able to get more help with your own code.  Edit: your comment about being a noob has been edited away.

Comment: How random does it need to be? (Also, you have an extra `O` in your character list.)

Comment: random enough to rarely have the same code, and thank you to signal that mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using LINQ.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(3)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        Dim random = New Random()
        Dim num1 = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4).Select(Function(s) s(random.Next(s.Length))).ToArray())
        Dim num2 = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4).Select(Function(s) s(random.Next(s.Length))).ToArray())
        Dim num3 = New String(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 4).Select(Function(s) s(random.Next(s.Length))).ToArray())
        Dim result = num1 & "-" & num2 & "-" & num3
        TextBox1.Text = result
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And how do you make the code enter in a text box? So when the timer is finished, the randomly generated code appears in a "readOnly" textbox

Answer (score 0):

With this, you'd just change your `TextBox1.Text =` to point to the `getNewRandomString()` function.

```
Private Function getNewRandomString() As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 4
            sb.Append(getNewRandomLetter())
        Next
        sb.Append("-")
    Next
    Return sb.ToString.Trim("-")
End Function

Private Function getNewRandomLetter() As Char
    Dim chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Return (chars(GetRandom(0, chars.Length - 1)))
End Function

Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Static Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max + 1)
End Function
```